# Yii2 ActiveRecord mocking with Mockery

Tags: unit-testing, activerecord, phpunit, yii2, mockery

I'm running phpunit with mockery (without DB/fixtures), but I have a trouble with mocking a model.

```
$customer = Mockery::mock(CustomerModel::class);
echo $customer->id;
```

Produces error:

`BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_1_models_Customer::hasAttribute() does not exist on this mock object`

Then I tried:

```
$customer->shouldReceive('hasAttribute')->andReturn(true);
```

But again, I run in to:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getDb() on a non-object in ..\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveRecord.php on line 135`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I know you are not accepting fixture answers, but I could not figure it out either. The problem I was trying to solve actually was mocking some methods in model so to avoid creating underlying fixtures.

So I ended up using `Proxy` pattern implementation in Mockery

```
private $_product;
public function testMe() 
{
   // Here we use fixtured instance of Product model to build a Proxy
   $this->_product = \Mockery::mock($this->product('product1')); 
   // somehow model attributes are inaccessible via proxy, but we can set them directly as a Proxy property
   $this->_product->id = 1; 
   $this->_product->shouldReceive('getPrice')->andReturn(1000);
   // assertions below
   ...
}
```

In this example `getPrice()` method from `Product` model returns `Product` price from related tables. And we mock it here so that we won't have to populate db with all related models fixtures. Nevertheless `Product` itself is still a fixture.

Maybe not the best solution, but managed to save me some CPU time while keeping unit tests decoupled.

Docs here
http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html

**update**:

I also made a small helper to solve attribute proxying problem

```
/**
 * @param \yii\base\Model $model
 * @return \Mockery\MockInterface
 */
private function setupMock($model)
{
    $mock = \Mockery::mock($model);
    foreach ($model->getAttributes() as $key => $value) {
        $mock->$key = $value;
    }
    return $mock;
}
```

This way all attributes and their corresponding values from original model become available in mock.

Answer (score 1):

Is [Traditional Partial Mock](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html#traditional-partial-mock) or [Passive Partial Mock](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html#passive-partial-mock) what you are looking for?

```
$customer = Mockery::mock(CustomerModel::className())->makePartial();
echo $customer->id;
```

The sample above would of course not return anything since id is not set, but wont throw any errors.

Comment: I think this is a problem in the first place. This approach creates new ``CustomerModel`` instance which is not persistent in terms of ActiveRecord. At the same time you cannot mock id because somehow ``$customer->id = 123`` won't assign value